# Bootstrap4 Alpha Carousel JS error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstraps JS CDN.

The code below is directly copied from there docs.

[http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/)

But I get this error and the slides don't change.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined(…)

```
<div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/600" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/600" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/600" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xi5rFc3kgzgJK7MZaSv9?p=preview) runs fine. Do you have more details ?

Comment: Also, there are multiple SO questions with the same error, but none seems to be a true duplicate

Comment: Thanks for this helped me figure out why. Basically I was been and idiot and not using the correct CDN.

Cheers guys.

Comment: Cool, you can answer your own question and mark it as resolved then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this helped me figure out why. Basically I was been and idiot and not using the correct CDN.